# Vim - Capture strings on Search and use on Replace

Tags: bash, search, vim, replace

I have a css selector such as:

```
#page-site-index .toolbar .items {
```

How do I capture the ".toolbar .items" part and use it on Replace part of Vim S&R, so this selector can turn into:

```
#page-site-index .toolbar .items, #page-site-login .toolbar .items {
```

Something like:

```
%s:/#page-site-index \(.toolbar .items\)/#page-site-index (the captured string), #page-site-login (the captured string)/g
```

Btw, I'm using the terminal version of Vim.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `\1`...  See the wiki here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

More explicitly:

```
%s:/#page-site-index \(.toolbar .items\)/#page-site-index \1, #page-site-login \1/g
```

Comment: Thanks! I've just had to change the (.toolbar .items) to \(.\+\), but your answer pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: the parentheses need to be backslashed

Comment: to summarize:
if you want to replace foobarbaz, fooquxbaz, fooanythingbaz with bar, qux, anything, do
:%s /foo\(.\+\)baz/\1/g

Answer (score 2):

try this command in your vim:

```
%s/\v#(page-site-index )(\.toolbar \.items)/&, #page-site-login \2/g
```

you could also use `\zs, \ze` and without grouping:

```
%s/#page-site-index \zs\.toolbar \.items\ze/&, #page-site-login &/g
```

keep golfing, if the text is just like what you gave in question, you could:

```
%s/#page-site-index \zs[^{]*\ze /&, #page-site-login &/g
```

Answer (score 2):

You've already grouped the interesting parts of the regular expression via `\(...\)` in your attempt. To refer to these *captured submatches* inside the replacement part, use `\1`, `\2`, etc., where the number refers to the first (opened) capture group, from left to right. There's also `\0` == `&` for the entire matched text. See `:help /\1` for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First type the `:` the get into command mode. Then issue the following command:

```
%s/#page-site-index .toolbar .items/#page-site-index .toolbar, #page-site-login
.toolbar .items/
```

Don't care about the formatting, its because of the stackoverflow markdown parser....

Comment: Thanks, but there's a lot of other selectors in this file and I would like to replace them all with a single command.

Comment: Yes this is specific for the question. Need to see the whole file to give a general answer.